# Find a Required Number in Python

Tags: python, string

One Number is there. If the number is trailing by zeros, three digits present before the trailing zeros should be appended to the output string.
If not trailing by zeros append the last three digits to the output string. If there is a preceding zero, it is ignored.

```
Sample input:362880  Sample OutPut:288
Sample input:892002300  Sample OutPut:23
Sample input:460  Sample OutPut:46
Sample input:1089  Sample OutPut:89
Sample input:5  Sample OutPut:5
```

I am new to python and have written the below code but not able to get the desired out put please help me with this.

```py
a='3620880'
b=''
for i in a[::-1]:
    if int(i)!=0 and len(b)<3:
        b=b+i
print(b[::-1])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [return index of last non-zero element in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41346403/return-index-of-last-non-zero-element-in-list)

Comment: What does it do for 11232140400 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
a.rstrip("0")[-3:].lstrip("0")
```

Use `lstrip()` and `rstrip()` on `'0'`s. The last 3 characters after `rstrip()` can be selected by `str[-3:]`.

**Examples**

```
'362880'.rstrip("0")[-3:].lstrip("0")
# '288'

'5'.rstrip("0")[-3:].lstrip("0")
# '5'

'1089'.rstrip("0")[-3:].lstrip("0")
# '89'
```

Comment: Thank You Bill for helping me to solve this problem.